# Understanding Create in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
##==================================User Model====
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,presence: true ,message: "Name can't be empty."
end

##===========================Migration==============
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name ,null: false
   end
  end
end

##==================================Schema.rb================
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151030131541) do
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
  end
end

##==========================Rails console==============
irb(main):009:0> User.create
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" DEFAULT VALUES
   (139.6ms)  commit transaction
=> #<User id: 4, name: nil>
irb(main):010:0>
```

I am using sqlite3 for database. Even though I have validation in model and NOT NULL condition in migration but still it is creating User with name as :nil , can somebody please explain how is this possible ?

Comment: did you reload the console after adding the validation?

Comment: Did you edit the migration after running it? If so, roll back the migration and re-migrate. (Don't do this in production or if you've committed code to a SCM like Git.)

Comment: @MichalSzyndel, yes, you're right I didn't reloaded the console and on reloading it is doing Rollback rather than Commit.

Comment: Then I think you should remove this question.

Comment: @charany1 Given that the the save appeared to work (the transaction committed) but the migration appears to have applied, I suspect that reloading the console only fixed one issue: the model validation. This could be hiding the fact that the database level migration isn't in place. To check this, see if you can still save an invalid model when the model validation is commented out (and after restarting the console). A save should raise a database error. A console reset won't have an effect on whether these kinds of errors occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validator is incorrect. It should be:

```
validates :name, presence: { message: "can't be empty." }
```

The text "Name" is added for you.

So:

Try rolling back your migration and re-migrating from the terminal:

```
rake db:rollback
rake db:migrate
```

Then reload your console and try:

```
user = User.create

user.id
#=> nil #Shows it has not saved

user.errors.full_messages

#=> ["Name can't be empty."]

User.count
#   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
#=> 0
```

Which is the behaviour I get when replicating your project and fixing your validation issue.

Comment: lol for accepting this answer. Not only didn't solve a problem but you only misinform the OP because presence validation has a default text (exactly the same) and you shouldn't overwrite it in the model, rather in translation files if at all.

Comment: thanks @A Fader Darkly , the issue was that I didn't reloaded console . On a similar line , I have another doubt that what is rule of thumb regarding setting validation of presence in Model for an attribute and NOT NULL in migration file for corresponding column , should we always use both for field ? Can you please explain ?

Comment: It is possible to fool Rails into bypassing the model validations, so it's a good idea to add them at the database level where they can't be circumvented, just as it is a good idea to add foreign key constraints where relevant. Unexpected nulls and bad references can easily cause 500 errors. Adding validations into the model allows Rails to more easily provide useful and friendly feedback to the user, rather than a blank server error. Both should be used.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel me: "Then reload your console and try..." chanary1: "the issue was that I didn't reloaded console". I agree regarding your assessment of the correct use of validation messages however.

Comment: Sorry, but by telling someone to rollback & migrate instead of just doing the right thing you teach voodoo programming. It's like "did you try turning it off and back on again?"

Comment: The system appeared to be in an indeterminate state. The schema showed a null constraint while the transaction wasn't rolling back when a null was provided. What to do in that situation? Rolling back and re-migrating is one way to get further information on the issue. (Others may include looking at the database table directly in the database console, but that's a little more involved.) But you're right, I could have elaborated on it. And yes, if it 'just works' then you don't know why it happened in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually creating the record. Per the [Rails docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/create):

> Tries to create a new record with the same scoped attributes defined in the relation. Returns the initialized object if validation fails.

The last sentence is the key...returns the `initialized` object. It's an invalid object and not yet added to the database.

Try `User.create!` since the bang method raises an exception instead of an invalidated object.